# Export Import Workflow SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, pnp-powershell, pnp, pnp-provision

I have got created a list workflow in SharePoint Designer for a SharePoint Online Site Collection.
Now I want to export this workflow and import it automatically to a new site collection during / after provisioning.

I found a PnP-PowerShell Cmd to export and import workflows.
The export works fine, but when I want to import the workflow, a exception is shown.

PowerShell Code ([QAZI MOBEEN - Export/Import SharePoint Designer Workflows using PowerShell](https://blog.kloud.com.au/2018/01/24/export-import-sharepoint-designer-workflows-using-powershell/)):

```
Connect-PnPOnline -Url $Url -Credentials $cred

Write-Host " "
Write-Host "Connected successfully to: $($Url)" -ForegroundColor Yellow

$ctx = Get-PnPContext
$parentContentTypeId = $null

$wf = Get-PnPWorkflowDefinition -Name $WFDefinitionName

if ($wf -eq $null)
{
    # Load workflow definition
    Publish-WorkflowDefinition (Get-PnPContext) $FilePath $WFDefinitionName

    Add-PnPWorkflowSubscription -Name $WFDefinitionName -DefinitionName $WFDefinitionName -List "Dokumente" -HistoryListName "Workflow History" -TaskListName "Aufgaben" -StartOnCreated
}
else
{
    Write-Host "Workflow definition $($WFDefinitionName) already exists.." -ForegroundColor Yellow
}
```

The error code is the following:

```
Add-PnPWorkflowSubscription : Der Objektverweis wurde nicht auf eine
Objektinstanz festgelegt.
In C:\Users\xxx\source\Workspaces\Dev\src\AddIns\Import.ps1:33 Zeichen:5
+     Add-PnPWorkflowSubscription -Name $WFDefinitionName -DefinitionNa ...
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : WriteError: (:) [Add-PnPWorkflowSubscription], N
   ullReferenceException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : EXCEPTION,SharePointPnP.PowerShell.Commands.Work
   flows.AddWorkflowSubscription
```

Because of this interruption the workflow is published as "reusable" workflow instead of list workflow.

I do not get the wrong params in this line:

```
Add-PnPWorkflowSubscription -Name $WFDefinitionName -DefinitionName $WFDefinitionName -List "Dokumente" -HistoryListName "Workflow History" -TaskListName "Aufgaben" -StartOnCreated
```

Do you have any ideas to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem.

If someone gets the same issue, you have to look in your xaml-file and replace GUID from your list(s).
Afterwards everything works and the workflow will be a list workflow

Answer (score 0):

You could export and import the workflow by SharePoint designer like the picture below.

[image]

For more detailed information, refer to the article below.

[Export-Import SharePoint Designer Workflow.](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/export-import-sharepoint-designer-workflow-vipul-jain)

Comment: Thanks for your reply and the idea to ex-/import wirkflows manual. But I need to import the workflow automatically during / after the provisioning of site collections.